# Typescript throws "is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }"

Tags: typescript, next.js

I know this has been discussed at length, but not other SO solutions seem to work, or I fail at implementing them.

I am brand new to typescript, and have the following:

```
import faker from "faker";
import React from "react";
import Index from "../components/Index";
import List from "../components/List";

interface Props {
  departments: [
    {
      id: number;
      name: string;
    }
  ];
}

const IndexPage: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ departments }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Index />
      <List departments={departments} />
    </>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  let departments: { id: number; name: string }[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 50; i += 1) {
    const name: string = await faker.company.companyName();
    departments = [...departments, { id: i, name }];
  }

  return {
    props: {
      departments,
    },
  };
}

export default IndexPage;
```

While I am not sure I even implemented TypeScript correctly, the compiler throws this error:

`Type '{ departments: [{ id: number; name: string; }]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
Property 'departments' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.`

The compiler underlines the departments prop on the `<List>` component.

Why is this error being thrown, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you show us the type on `List`?

Comment: @NicholasTower I am not sure what you mean. I don't have one in the List component. If i did, wouldn't it just be copy/paste the above code?

Comment: If you don't have a type on `List`, then typescript has no idea what props are legal to pass into it. You will need to add a type to `List`. I expect it will be similar to the type on IndexPage, but i don't know what your requirements are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript is trying to tell you that you're trying to give the property `departments` to an object (in this case, a React component) which doesn't have that property on its type.

The type `'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'` is just the default typing for a react component; provided that `departments` is not included in the props of that type (and it isn't) then you can't pass that prop to the `List` component.

To fix this, you just need to add `departments`to the definition of `List`'s props